# Cell2mat returns error: cat: dimension mismatch

Tags: octave

I have a large cell array with a dimension of 1311114x2. An extract of my data looks like this.

```
Rotation angle  Measured distance
-358,506    26,992
-358,758    26,993
-359,010    26,992
-359,262    26,993
-359,514    26,992
-359,766    26,992
-0,018  26,993
-0,270  26,991
-0,522  26,992
-0,774  26,992
-1,044  26,993
-1,296  26,992
```

To create my output variable I'm using the cell2mat function

```
data = [cell2mat(raw(:,1)), cell2mat(raw(:,2))];
```

and receive the following error message.

```
error: cat: dimension mismatch
error: called from
    cell2mat at line 80 column 11
    Cloud_reconstruction at line 102 column 6
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that the values in your `raw` cell array are strings (or characters arrays). Since these strings have varying lengths, the desired concatenation won't work as also stated in the error message.

You can use Octave's [`str2num`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/str2num.html) function to convert strings to numerical values. That won't work out-of-the-box here, since you also have commas in your strings. It seems, these are decimal separators. You need to replace these commas, e.g. using Octave's [`strrep`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/strrep.html) method. With the help of Octave's [`cellfun`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/cellfun.html) method, the above mentioned function(s) can be applied to all entries of a cell array.

Here's my solution:

```matlab
raw = {
  '-358,506',    '26,992';
  '-358,758',    '26,993';
  '-359,010',    '26,992';
  '-0,018',      '26,993'
}

data = cellfun(@(x)str2num(x), strrep(raw, ',', '.'))
```

That results in:

```
  raw =
  {
    [1,1] = -358,506
    [2,1] = -358,758
    [3,1] = -359,010
    [4,1] = -0,018
    [1,2] = 26,992
    [2,2] = 26,993
    [3,2] = 26,992
    [4,2] = 26,993
  }

  data =

    -358.506000    26.992000
    -358.758000    26.993000
    -359.010000    26.992000
      -0.018000    26.993000
```

Hope that helps!